# When will Osmos and Shatter be available for Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: software-center, 12.10

When will Osmos and Shatter be available for Ubuntu 12.10? Both are only available for 12.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.10 is very new. Some applications, like MyUnity or Osmos, aren't avaliable yet. We have to wait until they go to the Quantal repositories.

Alternatively, it seems that Shatter is avaliable to download for cross-platform on their website, give it a check, but it looks as you'll have to buy it again! It's [here](http://www.shattergame.com/).

Comment: Ah, thanks. Yeah, both can be bought via their websites, and since I got them via the Humble Bundle it's fine, I just wanted the nice installation and updates via USC. Is there perhaps any way to trick USC into thinking it's still on 12.04? I know that the games run fine, since when I upgraded my other machine, it all still works well. Thanks.